# How do you isolate/silo websites on an Ubuntu w/ LEMP stack?

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server with NGINX/PHP/MySQL with multiple website hosted on it.

Several of them are Wordpress websites for friends, so they can upload their own plugins and potentially malicious code.

How can I prevent scripts in their web folders from accessing other website folders and my home folder?

Comment: This is most likely going to end in disaster and will take a fair amount of setup and maintenance, because you will have to isolate both the website files **and databases** for each friend. Are these just hobby sites? Would your friends care if you had to wipe the machine and start over after their _"own plugins and potentially malicious code"_ produce the expected outcome? You are probably better off putting them on individual cheap VPSs and let someone more experienced worry about it.

Comment: @TomBrossman - That's fine. Can you tell me how to isolate the web files? Databases will just be owned by different mysql users.

Comment: See [this canonical question](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) for an overview of file/folder permissions and groups, users, etc. It can be done because this is how shared hosting companies do it but they have more time and expertise and get paid to deal with this. You have to secure the whole stack and constantly maintain it for your friends' hobby websites. Nice thing to offer, but maybe not worth the trouble long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer for NGINX was to create php-fpm pools for each site/virtual host.

These pools each have their own user, and that use has no access to any files outside of the pool. So they are totally isolated.

[Here is an in-depth tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Just [create new account](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps) and install WordPress separately.

Each WordPress site using separate database from phpmyadmin, so If your friends are not developer, then allowing FTP access is not good idea at all, they can do many things directly from WordPress dashboard.

Comment: I'm not concerned about my friends messing around, I'm concerned about malicious code jumping back 2 directories and affecting other sites.